# Truncated incorrect double value in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

I am trying to add strings with a separator ',' in the UPDATE statement in a column  as follows:

```
    const sql="UPDATE Events SET rejectedBy=rejectedBy+? WHERE id=2"
    db.query(sql,[request.params.name+','],(err,result)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
    })
```

But I am getting error like:

```
    Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'berlin7,'
```

where berlin7 is the value of request.params.name.

My table column is

```
    rejectedBy varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: You cannot sum texts. You probably want `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Ok can you give example?

Comment: Sure, Please check the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much!